# Silverlight Forms Authentication

Tags: silverlight, forms, authentication

I have Forms authentication in a Silverlight app working. I am checking if the Login was successful.

How do I get the User credentials for User? Already logged in and with the UI?

```
       private void CheckForLogin()
    {
      Authentication.AuthenticationServiceClient proxy = new Authentication.AuthenticationServiceClient();
      proxy.IsLoggedInCompleted += new EventHandler<Authentication.IsLoggedInCompletedEventArgs>(proxy_IsLoggedInCompleted);
      proxy.IsLoggedInAsync();

    }

    void proxy_IsLoggedInCompleted(object sender, Authentication.IsLoggedInCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

      if (e.Result)
      {
        //Get the User Credentials here:

      }
      else
      {

        var loginWindow = new LoginWindow();
        loginWindow.Closed += new EventHandler(loginWindow_Closed);
        loginWindow.Show();
      }
    }

    void loginWindow_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      LoginWindow loginWindow = (LoginWindow)sender;
      bool? result = loginWindow.DialogResult;

      if (result.HasValue && result.Value)
      {

        //Get the User Credentials here:

      }
    }
```

How should I proceed from here?

Comment: do you have access to WebContext.Current.User ?